# Is there a way to have 2 devices on a single Google account

Tags: applications, multiple-devices

My Mom has a Samsung tablet that she uses 90% of the time. I bought her a Chromebook before I knew my brother had gotten her the Samsung. She uses the tablet for quickly looking at Facebook and Gmail because she can walk around with it and the Chromebook at the table for Internet browsing because the Chromebook has a much larger screen.

Recently she wanted to be able to check her bank account so I thought it best to put it on the device used least and less likely to be lost, the Chromebook. But when I try and install the app from Google Play only the Samsung is listed.

Is there any way to add a device to that Google account. I already have it so the Chromebook logs in automatically to Facebook and Gmail for her, that way she can be up to date on either device because it is the same GMail and Facebook account. Is that the same as logging into the Google Account? If not how do I get there?

I do not want to copy paid apps to 2 devices or anything that would be seen as cheating, I just want it easy for her to check e-mail and Facebook from either device without having to teach her to log in and out.

Thank you for your help
Philip

Answer (score 5):

Google Play is only for Android apps. Android apps do not work on the Chromebook, which is why you only see the tablet listed in the Play Store. The Chromebook is basically the Chrome Web browser wrapped in a keyboard and screen and that is it.

You can check the Chrome Web Store for an app for her bank, but even if there is one, it is likely just going to be a shortcut that loads the bank's website. If there isn't an app for it in the Chrome Web Store, just bookmark it for her.

And to answer the overall question, you can have as many Android devices tied to the Google account as you want and it isn't a problem having a paid app on more than one device, as long as it is signed in to that Google account.